# Node Mocha test log save to disk

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

Need to save the test logging to the disk

I have tried the below code

```
  mocha -R spec  test/**/*_test.js   >  report
```

suppose any test case failed it not log into the 'report' file. Please suggest best way to log the test report.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should redirect `stderr` to that logfile too:

```
mocha -R spec  test/**/*_test.js > report 2>&1
```

**EDIT**: if you want the contents to be sent both to a file *and* the console:

```
mocha -R spec  test/**/*_test.js 2>&1 | tee report
```

Comment: getting some junk char in the file "[0m[0m
[0m  controller[0m"

Comment: Call Mocha with `-C` or `--no-colors`

Comment: thanks... but currently write only in file not in console... Need both

Comment: really appreciated your input... but need to run with color in console and log file without color if you suggest good option really help me lot.

Comment: My report file shows `mocha' is not recognized as an internal or external command`  
Please help with it!

Comment: @AjitejKaushik so you need to install Mocha (properly): `npm i mocha -g`

Comment: @robertklep its still persisting the same error. the content of my report file is `'mocha' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`
And when i run this command on git bash, it shows `mocha: command not found`

Comment: @AjitejKaushik you should probably ask a separate question for this, it's not really related to this one.

Comment: In my code I have some console.log and console.error (and I don't want to include any external library to handle logs ). But my CI/CD process needs to analyze the generated xml. So in my test.js file I had to overwrite those methods:

`console.log = (x)=>{}`

Comment: @DavidValdivieso the downside of that would be that you won't be able to see any errors that Mocha throws (AFAIK, it uses `console.log` for that).

Answer (score 5):

The question does not specify what the log is going to be used for. If you need stack traces in the report, then you can't use `json-stream` because this reporter does not include the traces. However, if what you want is something that can be parsed trivially and only thing you care about is knowing the status of the tests and not *why* they failed, then the `json-stream` reporter works nicely:

```
$ mocha -R json-stream > report
```

You get a list of regularly formatted lines:

```
["start",{"total":1}]
["fail",{"title":"q","fullTitle":"blah q"}]
["end",{"suites":1,"tests":1,"passes":0,"pending":0,"failures":1,"start":"2014-01-08T18:10:27.764Z","end":"2014-01-08T18:10:27.768Z","duration":4}]
```

Then you can grep for failed tests easily:

```
$ grep '^\["fail"' report
```

The output could also be passed to a tool that narrows it down to what you want and formats it nicely to go in an email, an IM message or something else. I've used this method quite a lot when running a test suite with thousands of tests where what I cared about most was quickly getting a list of what had failed.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can simplify to just

```
mocha --colors  ./test/**/*_test.js 2>&1 | tee ./reports/report.log
```